# What is the right-side white area of XCode editor?

Tags: xcode, editor

[image: my captured screen]

Does anyone know why?

**EDIT**

I've found it. It was a page guide.
After i unchecked it, it disappeared
[image: this]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me.

1. What have you selected to get this?
2. Is this behavior all the time or you get rid of it when you restart or build your project?

If it happens to be a bug I would recommend you to report a bug to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).